# Copy Wav files older than 3 months to archive, creating year\month paths

Tags: powershell

I was hoping someone can help me out with this script which is currently baffling me, I'm not very good at powershell ;)

What I'm trying to achieve is a script that will scan folders and subfolders of my source, looking for *.wav files older than 60 days and then move them to an archive destination, creating a folder structure of \year\month

This is what i've got

```
$SourceDir = "d:\test"
$DestinationDir = "e:\test"
$files = get-childitem $SourceDir *.wav
foreach ($file in $files) 
{
$Directory = $DestinationDir + "" + $file.CreationTime.Date.ToString('yyyy') + "\" + $file.CreationTime.Date.ToString('MM-MMM')
if (!(Test-Path $Directory))
{
New-Item $directory -type directory
}
where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-61)} | move-item $file.fullname $Directory
}
```

The script runs without error but doesn't move files :/

--

Following on from Keiths comments below, my script looks as so:

```
$SourceDir = "d:\test\"
$DestinationDir = "e:\test\"
$date = (get-date).AddDays(-91)
$files = get-childitem -literalpath $SourceDir *.wav
foreach ($file in $files) 
{
$Directory = $DestinationDir + "" + $file.CreationTime.Date.ToString('yyyy') + "\" + $file.CreationTime.Date.ToString('MM-MMM')
if (!(Test-Path $Directory))
{
New-Item $directory -type directory
}
if ($file.LastWriteTime -lt $date) {
    Write-Host $file
    move-item -LiteralPath $file.fullname -Destination $Directory
}
}
```

And is working perfectly! Thanks Keith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where-Object is never at the beginning of a pipeline.  It requires input to populate the `$_` variable you usually use to compare against.  Replace that line with:

```
if ($file.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddMonths(-3)) {
    move-item $file.fullname $Directory
}
```

Although I would compute the date outside the loop:

```
$date = (get-date).AddMonths(-3)
```

And use that inside the loop:

```
...
if ($file.LastWriteTime -lt $date) {
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $file.fullname -Destination $Directory
}
...
```

Comment: A step in the right direction! You are of course right, i've made the modifcation and now the script creates the folder structure but fails to move any files (i have files in there greater than 6 months old)

Comment: Try the updated answer (using -LiteralPath) to make sure it works on filename's with special chars like `[ ]`.  If that still doesn't work, put this above the Move-Item - `Write-Host $file` to make sure the `if` test is actually finding any old files.  BTW your question says 3 months but your test is for 61 days which is ~ 2 months?

Comment: Hi Keith, hope you had a good weekend ;). Advice followed properly this time, very tired on Friday, and I can see that its because the if test isn't finding files. Typical filename is "[Boardroom]_3000-6%2A%2A7_20150723135940(259088).wav" - have updated the above script

Comment: Ignore my last, It is working perfectly! Thank you Keith